# PHPMailer with SMTP and outlook

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMailer with SMTP.  It fails due to a "Relay Access denied ATTR36..." error. It suggests a url for further details. Actually quite informative, usually I would stop here and fix the apparent relay issue however I have a second script that works with SMTP to the same host. It also auto detects 'tls'.

```
//Script 1 Fails
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Host = '************.mail.protection.outlook.com';
//$mail->SMTPSecure='tls'; //I've tried setting this but still the same results. 
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SetFrom('FromEmail@************.com');
$mail->addAddress('ToEmail@************.com');
$mail->Subject = 'TEST SUBJECT';

$mail->msgHTML($content);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

So to double that check the server accepts relaying I used SendEmail from  http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/ to test.

//Script 2 Works

```
sendEmail.pl -f FromEmail@************.com -t ToEmail@************.com -u 'TEST SUBJECT' -s '************.mail.protection.outlook.com' -m $content
```

This worked first time.

I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with tls and the options I have/haven't set. Anyone any ideas? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: check your maillog it will give you details

Comment: And set the value of `SMTPDebug` so, that it provides the most detailed log entry for the error.

Comment: The most common cause of an unexpected "Relay access denied" is that you have not authenticated against the server you're sending through, which indeed you have not. Open relays are very bad things, and generally indicate that the server is misconfigured. It would help if you showed the debug output.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I accidentally transposed 2 characters in the "from" email  in my PHPMailer test script. The incorrect spelling caused the "Relay Access Denied" error.  My mistake. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.